# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, isnumeric

First, let me state I have read various similar posts and haven't been able to identify the similarities between the problem that other posters have had with this error message and the situation I've encountered.  Perhaps I'm not searching correctly, but here's the scenario.  I'm trying to search for values in a table that are less than 70 when converted to a numeric value.  Sometimes the value can be stored with a comma (i.e. 3,080 etc.) so I have a replace statement to remove the comma.  The `obsValue` column in the queries below is `varchar(2000)` and I'm guessing that may have something to do with it.  My initial query worked:

```
Select name, obsValue
From database.dbo.table
Where name in ('LDL') 
and isnumeric(obsvalue) = 1 
and cast(replace(obsvalue,',','') as decimal(18)) < 70
```

This brings back expected values, but it's not the only `name` I'm trying to search for.  Other examples include `('LDL(CALC)')`. Using a `UNION` statement will allow me to union queries together but unfortunately I don't control the application code and this is not an option.  The only option I have available is using an `IN` clause, so ultimately the query will look like this when I'm searching for a variety of `name` values:

```
Select name, obsValue
From database.dbo.table
Where name in ('LDL', 'LDL(CALC)') 
and isnumeric(obsvalue) = 1 
and cast(replace(obsvalue,',','') as decimal(18)) < 70
```

And unfortunately doing it this way is where I get the error message.  I apologize if this has already been answered elsewhere.  Please link and I will give credit where credit is due.

Comment: what error are you getting?  Also, for debugging, try breaking it into pieces to see which function is causing the error.  Test running only the in() function, isnumeric(), and cast().  Probably only one part of your query is generating the error.

Comment: Maybe the decimal point?, what happens if you do your cast as `DECIMAL(36,6)` or something like that?

Comment: @beth It's the title of the question, Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.  Just saw your edit as well, the issue isn't in any one function, the issue is when I try to include more than one value in the `IN` clause.  Ex.  `IN ('LDL')` works, `IN ('LDL(CALC)')` works, `IN ('LDL', 'LDL(CALC)')` fails.

@Lamak `DECIMAL(36,6)` causes the same error

Comment: What if you try to cast it to a bigger datatype?, what happens if you cast it as `MONEY`?

Comment: Then you have a value that is really too big to be casted as numeric, maybe you can find that value doing a `SELECT` on your table and ordering by `LEN(obsValue) DESC`

Comment: @Lamak if that were the case, that one value is causing the problem, then the first query wouldn't work at all.  Again, the issue isn't that the query doesn't work with one value versus the other, the issue is that it doesn't work work when trying to use both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the IsNumeric(obsvalue) with (select obsvalue where isnumeric(obsvalue) = 1).

```
Select name, obsValue
From database.dbo.table
Where name in ('LDL', 'LDL(CALC)') 
and isnumeric(obsvalue) = 1 
and cast(replace((select obsvalue where isnumeric(obsvalue) = 1),',','') as decimal(18)) < 70
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be values in obsvalue that are too big for your cast( as decimal) function but you don't care about anyways because they don't meet your in() criteria.

Try applying the cast() in a subquery, limiting your query to obsvalues you actually need to convert.

Also, since the commas only exist if the value is greater than 999, and you're testing for values less than 70, you don't need the replace.  In fact, you could exclude any row containing a comma because you know it's too high.

Comment: I didn't state this in my OP, but the value 70 is arbitrary, it's set by the user, while an LDL value of 3,000 would never happen, the `IN` clause and the numeric value to test against CAN be set by the end user.  My fault for not being more clear.

Comment: OK, then keep replacing the commas, but try breaking the query into a nested one with the in() clause in the inner query and the cast() in the outer query.  Then, if you still get the error (which you might, if users are picking the condition,) you'll know it's valid (crap in the db)

Comment: I gave the answer above, but +1'd* this as well as your suggestions had me going in the right direction before the answer above was provided.  Thanks for the input. (* tried to, this is my first SO question, so no rep... DOH!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SQL Server is optimizing the query differently when there are multiple items in the IN clause. You can use a CASE statement to prevent the optimization

```
SELECT name, obsvalue
FROM database.dbo.table 
WHERE (CASE WHEN ( isnumeric(obsvalue) = 1 
             AND name in ('LDL', 'LDL(CALC)')) 
       THEN cast(replace(obsvalue,',','') as decimal(18))
       ELSE null END) < 70
```

Comment: It seems odd to me that the optimizer would be the culprit here, although I can't argue with this as this does allow the query to work.

Comment: Swapped out the answer per the original answerer's request.